# Is asking for people to think up new specific words on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Regarding this question: [I need a word for my obscure phobia for hard, smooth structures](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294777/i-need-a-word-for-my-obscure-phobia-for-hard-smooth-spheres)

The questioner seems to realize that his situation is... unique and all the answers are just trying to create words based on greek roots. It just has no value at all for future visitors, the answers won't be understood by other people (and given that language is all about communication that's a pretty big issue) and it could even be argued that the answers are primary opinion based (given that every answer is thinking up new unique words). So, do we want questions like that?

Comment: It's a gray area.  I voted to close it as opinion based.

Comment: Single word requests are allowed to include neologisms, but that doesn't make them good questions.

Comment: Related: [When are neologisms On-Topic?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/when-are-neologisms-on-topic)

Comment: Related: [Are uncommon neologisms without a notable source acceptable as an answer?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5350/are-uncommon-neologisms-without-a-notable-source-acceptable-as-an-answer)

Comment: @ curiousdannii 'Single word requests are allowed to include neologisms' is imprecise. I've come across a stance saying that neologisms as found on the internet say are on-topic but 'propose a new word for this' aren't.

Comment: There was once a tag called coin-a-term, it has since been made into a synonym with [neologism](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/neologisms/synonyms)

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch in  your question title and what I found at the question itself. Looking at your overview, I expected to find some whimsical request for a nonsense word. Going to the question, I found a thoughtful request for a "best prefix," which is not quite the same thing. It seems like a fair question for a community of etymologists.